# innerhtml cannot be chage (keeps resetting)

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

im trying to change the innerhtml of an element but it keeps reseting back to "ddd" on every click of the button

```html
<form>
<p id="passError">ddd</p>
<button id="submit">Login</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(){changeit()};
function changeit()
{
    pError = document.getElementById("passError");
    pError.innerHTML = ("wrong password");
</script>
```

Comment: You forget closing curly bracket `}`

Comment: thanks i changed it yet it still does not change "ddd"

Comment: The form is submitted, and a new page will be loaded as a server response. Use `button` type of `button`, prevent the default action in the click handler, remove the form ...

Comment: @strawheart if a post answers what you are looking for, don't forget to mark it as "Selected Answer". It'll help future people with same question :)

Answer (score 0):

First you are missing the } on the function and then with the submit you are submitting the form which you have to prevent. You don't need a wrapper function for the changeit function you may pass it directly to the onclick variable.

```
<form>
<p id="passError">ddd</p>
<button id="submit">Login</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = changeit;
function changeit(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    pError = document.getElementById("passError");
    pError.innerHTML = "wrong password";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one thing and have another typo mistake:

- you forgot the closing curly bracket `}` at the end of your function `changeit()` as mentionned by @antyrat;
- you want to put directly the string in the innerHTML assignation, *not using parenthesis*. (see the [innerHTML documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) from MDN)

Moreover, you can also pass directly your `changeit` function instead of using an anonymous function and put your `pError` in a proper declarated variable. :)

As you are using a `<form>`, you also need to prevent the default behavior of the submit button by calling the [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) function on the click event in your function.

The following code is working. I corrected these elements and just add some indentation and spacing to have a code more user-friendly.

```html
<form>
  <p id="passError">ddd</p>
  <button id="submit">Login</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = changeit;

function changeit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var pError = document.getElementById("passError");
    pError.innerHTML = "wrong password";
}
</script>
```

Comment: strange. this works when i run the snippet on stackoverflow, however it does not work when i run it with firefox

Comment: @strawheart Exactly, it's my fault. The submit button you have has a default behavior in Firefox and makes the web page reload. To stop it, you have to add `evt.preventDefault();` in your `changeit` function. I'm editing my snippet right now.